# Getting wrong Unicode from Habenero API in Python

Tags: python, unicode, habanero

I am calling the [Habanero API](https://github.com/sckott/habanero) which is a front end to [CrossRef](https://www.crossref.org/). With this code:

```
import json
from habanero import cn

x = cn.content_negotiation(ids="10.1051/0004-6361/201628812",
    format = "text", style = 'elsevier-harvard')

print(u'{0}'.format(x))
print(json.dumps(x, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```

I get the following output (emphasis mine):

Hawkins, K., Masseron, T., **JofrÃ©**, P., Gilmore, G., Elsworth, Y., Hekker, S., 2016. An accurate and self-consistent chemical abundance catalogue for the APOGEE/Keplersample. Astronomy & Astrophysics 594, A43.

"Hawkins, K., Masseron, T., **Jofr\u00c3\u00a9**, P., Gilmore, G., Elsworth, Y., Hekker, S., 2016. An accurate and self-consistent chemical abundance catalogue for the APOGEE/Keplersample. Astronomy & Astrophysics 594, A43.\n"

The third author's name should be **Jofré**, so I imagine the final character was supposed to be \uc3a9. It seems from the JSON dump that it is sending \u00c3\u00a9 instead. Am I doing something wrong in either requesting or decoding?

Comment: Yup, something's going wrong with decoding: the UTF-8 representation of "é", which is the bytes sequence `C3 A9`, is being interpreted as Latin-1, which results in "Ã©". This is shown clearly in the JSON output, which should be "\u00e9". I suspect it's habanero's fault, and filing an issue on their GitHub repo was the right thing to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed in [git repo](https://github.com/sckott/habanero/issues/73). h/t @sckott.